# Angular clone object from function

Tags: json, angularjs

I try clone my response json, but the id is the same..

I want to clone an item in my json to facilitate the addition of content.
The problem is following the same ID, then the answer is to update and no new item ..

the function:

```
$scope.cloneItem = function(id) {

    $scope.itemtoclone = allDB.get({section: section, id: id}, function(){

        $scope.itemnew = new allDB({section: section});

        $scope.itemnew = angular.copy($scope.itemtoclone);

        $scope.itemnew.$save(function(){
            $mdToast.show($mdToast.simple({position: 'top right'}).content('Clone criado!'));
        });

    });

}
```

and the response:

```
GET http://localhost:5000/posts/25 304 Not Modified 7ms 
POST http://localhost:5000/25 201 Created 2ms
```

json object to clone:

```
{
  "id": 25,
  "title": "Willian busca protagonismo igual ao de Neymar: \"Sempre joguei assim\"",

  "subtitle": "Com 94% de aproveitamento nos passes na estreia da Copa América, jogador tem chamado a
 responsabilidade e dividido a missão de criar os lances com o camisa 10",
  "slug": "brasil-post-1",
  "published": true,
  "originalDate": "2015-06-16T03:00:00.000Z",
  "excerpt": "Com 94% de aproveitamento nos passes na estreia da Copa América",
  "$promise": {},
  "$resolved": true,
  "cats": [
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
    7
  ]
}
```

Resolved, It was not quite what I wanted, but I help!

```
$scope.cloneItem = function(id) {

    $scope.getclone = allDB.get({section: section, id: id}, function(response){

        console.log(response);

        $scope.itemnew = new allDB({section: section});

        $scope.itemnew.title = response.title;
        $scope.itemnew.subtitle = response.subtitle;
        $scope.itemnew.excerpt = response.excerpt;


        $scope.itemnew.$save(function(){
            $mdToast.show($mdToast.simple({position: 'top right'}).content('Clone criado!'));
        });

    });
}
```

Comment: Did you try `angular.copy`?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy

Comment: what exactly do you want to clone? Is this a `$resource` object? Code shown doesn't make much sense when you assign the variable 2 times. Please provide all details when asking a question. Broken code that doesn't work is not a substitute for a proper explanation of the issue and what is or isn't working

Comment: Same error... copy ID, not create new id..

Comment: For creating content, it is significant but, at least for me ..

Comment: if this is a $resource your function is missing the response argument and you are trying to clone the wrong thing